# Calculating Stock in Hand in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider a dataframe (converted to dictionary for posting here) of inventory of products

```
[
  {
    "production_batch_start_date": "2019-07-15",
    "rm/pm_code": "abc",
    "consumed_qty": 0,
    "purchased_quantity": 0,
    "opening_stock": 58819.8
  },
  {
    "production_batch_start_date": "2019-07-15",
    "rm/pm_code": "efg",
    "consumed_qty": 0,
    "purchased_quantity": 0,
    "opening_stock": 0
  },
  {
    "production_batch_start_date": "2019-07-15",
    "rm/pm_code": "hij",
    "consumed_qty": 150,
    "purchased_quantity": 10,
    "opening_stock": 39715.4
  },
  {
    "production_batch_start_date": "2019-07-16",
    "rm/pm_code": "abc",
    "consumed_qty": 6807,
    "purchased_quantity": 0,
    "opening_stock": "nan"
  },
  {
    "production_batch_start_date": "2019-07-16",
    "rm/pm_code": "efg",
    "consumed_qty": 11432,
    "purchased_quantity": 0,
    "opening_stock": "nan"
  },
  {
    "production_batch_start_date": "2019-07-16",
    "rm/pm_code": "hij",
    "consumed_qty": 20,
    "purchased_quantity": 5,
    "opening_stock": "nan"
  }
]
```

I would like to find add another column called `stock in hand` which would be giving me a value of quantity left at end of each day. It can be calculated by summing `purchased_quantity` of the day with previous day's stock in hand and subtracting with `consumed_qty` of that particular day.

The `opening_stock` gives me the initial value stock for the first day of inventory taken. Other all days, it is `NaN`.

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "production_batch_start_date": "2019-07-15",
    "rm/pm_code": "hij",
    "purchased_quantity": 10,
    "opening_stock": 39715.4,
    "consumed_qty": 150,
    "stock_in_hand": 39575.4
  },
  {
    "production_batch_start_date": "2019-07-16",
    "rm/pm_code": "hij",
    "purchased_quantity": 5,
    "opening_stock": "NaN",
    "consumed_qty": 20,
    "stock_in_hand": 39560
  }
]
```

Please let me know how this can be done in Python.

Comment: Can you add expected output DataFrame?

Comment: @jezrael I have Added!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need subtract values by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
#if necessary sort data
df = df.sort_values(['production_batch_start_date', 'rm/pm_code'])

#if necessary aggregate data
#df=df.groupby(['production_batch_start_date', 'rm/pm_code'], as_index=False).sum(min_count=1)
df["stock_in_hand"] = df['opening_stock'].sub(df['consumed_qty'], fill_value=0)
df['stock_in_hand'] = df.groupby('rm/pm_code')['stock_in_hand'].cumsum()
print (df)

  production_batch_start_date rm/pm_code  consumed_qty  purchased_quantity  \
0                  2019-07-15        abc             0                   0   
1                  2019-07-15        efg             0                   0   
2                  2019-07-15        hij           150                  10   
3                  2019-07-16        abc          6807                   0   
4                  2019-07-16        efg         11432                   0   
5                  2019-07-16        hij            20                   5   

   opening_stock  stock_in_hand  
0        58819.8        58819.8  
1            0.0            0.0  
2        39715.4        39565.4  
3            NaN        52012.8  
4            NaN       -11432.0  
5            NaN        39545.4
```

Comment: I will try this! Thanks